# Replace variables inside txt file programatically from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have some issues trying to make a thing, if any 1 here can give me an advice or some help will be nice.

I need to read some information from a txt file and put all that info to a textbox (this is ready and done)

but the textfile have some variables like %userName% that i need to replace programatically in vb.net, any 1 have an idea how to do it?

example of text file:

hello %userName% , this is an automated report of the uses of your account.

this is what the txt file have in it, when i read it to vb.net and put that info into a textbox is done right, but the question is how to replace the %userNams% for some text in another textbox and replaced when i press a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("%userName%", TextBox2.Text)
```

Comment: i have some doubts, what is the a.replace? how i can use that code when i do this to fill the textbox 
Dim sReader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(“c:\newTextFile.txt”)
   
txt.AppendText(sReader.ReadToEnd)

Comment: When you have filled `TextBox1` call the `Replace` function on the button click to replace the string "%userName%" with the value from `TextBox2`

Comment: i have tested that code     TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("%userName%", TextBox2.Text)   but when i click the button doesnt do nothing on the textbox

Comment: thanks and sorry for stupid response, i was making a stupid thing, it works and works awesome, thanks for your help